# HashMap updating ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm just starting to learn to use HashMap and reading the java tutorial, but I'm having trouble.

I'm trying to update the List inside a HashMap but I want to get the List of that key, is there a way to update a specific List of the key instead of having to make...5 different Lists and updating those?

```
 HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        mMap.put("A", list);
        mMap.put("B", list);
        mMap.put("C", list);
        mMap.put("D", list);

        Iterator iter = mMap.entrySet().iterator();

        if (mMap.containsKey("A"))
        {   
            Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
            list.add("test");
            mMap.put("A",list);
            System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());
        }
        else if (mMap.containsKey("B"))
        {   
            Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
            list.add("entry");
            mMap.put("B",list);
            System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());
        }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
mMap.get("A").add("test");
mMap.get("B").add("entry");
```

Comment: ah! you beat me to the answer ;-)

Comment: How can this get 3 upvotes when it misses the fact that he put the same List into every map entry?  :-)

Comment: I just answered his basic question: Is there a simpler method to update the list that what I'm doing?

Answer (score 7):

1. Like @Tudor said, use mMap.get("A").add("foo");
2. You put the same exact list into each map entry.  You initial lines should be

```
    mMap.put("A", new ArrayList());
    mMap.put("B", new ArrayList()); 
    ...
    mMap.put("Z", new ArrayList());
```

Alternatvely, write a method that checks on the fly

```
public synchronized void myAdd(String key, String value) {
   List<String> there = mMap.get(key);
   if (there == null) {
      there = new ArrayList<String>();
      mMap.put(key, there);
   }
   there.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably mean:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> mMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    mMap.put("A", new ArrayList<String>());
    mMap.put("B", new ArrayList<String>());
    mMap.put("C", new ArrayList<String>());
    mMap.put("D", new ArrayList<String>());

    if (mMap.containsKey("A"))
    {   
        mMap.get("A").add("test");
        System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());
    }
    else if (mMap.containsKey("B"))
    {   
        mMap.get("B").add("entry");
        System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());
    }
   ...
```

I wonder if you really need those containsKey checks either!
HTH!

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your case you can use [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html)'s [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and [ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) interfaces and [ArrayListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) implementation.

[Choosing right collection](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65) (in link there are only standard collections but `Multimap` is right in this case) makes code more readable:

```
ListMultimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
myMultimap.put("A", "test");
myMultimap.put("B", "entry");
```

then `myMultimap.get("A")` gives you list (`ArrayList` instance in fact) with one element: "test", while `myMultimap.get("C")` gives you empty list.

Comparing to `Map<String, List<String>>` approach:

- you don't have to initialize "C" key with empty list for it,
- you don't have `null`s checks (no `NullPointerException`s),
- you don't have to do other checks such as `myMap.containsKey("A")`,
- you write less code,
- so your code is less bug-prone,
- etc., etc.

---

P.S. Instead of:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

[use interfaces, not classes when using collections](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=26) i.e.:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

and even better Guava's "static constructors" (you don't repeat code):

```
Map<String, List<String>> mMap = Maps.newHashMap()
```

when knowledge about implementation is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the same list as a value with different keys, in your case keys A,B,C, and D all point to the same list, and access and update the list through one key the changes will then be visible in all the lists. Each key points to the same list structure.

If you want the lists to be different you need to use different for different keys you need to use a different list.

You could automate the process, say by making your own insert method that clones the given list.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Map<String ,List<String>> mMap=new HashMap<>();
    public  void myAdd(String key, String value) {
        try {
            lock.lock();
        List<String> there =mMap.get(key)==null?new ArrayList<>():mMap.get(key);
        there.add(value);
        mMap.put(key, there);
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```